# OS X Terminal: 'ls' with 'grep !'

Tags: macos, terminal

I would like to list all files in folder without one. I created this command `ls /Users/MyName/Library/Safari | grep ! "Extensions"`. The problem is that the Terminal doesn't understand the not (`!`). How to change that it works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do it like this:

```
ls /path/to/folder | grep -v "Extensions"
```

`grep -v "Extensions"` excludes "Extensions" from the listing.

Comment: With removing `grep -n ""` it is what I mean, thanks! :)

Comment: `grep -n` adds line numbers :-)

Comment: How do I integrate `-exec` in the command line?

Comment: @user121028 That is a separate question - find is the command you need to read the manual/tutorial for

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on extended glob in bash.

```
    shopt -s extglob
    cd $HOME/Library/Safari
    ls -d -- !(Extentions)
```